# How to split node_modules on different branches on Git

Tags: git, react-native, github

I am trying to split my GitHub branches into different folders.

I've got the branch: **Master** which is the main (stable) branch and **Development** which I use to implement new features into my project.

It happens a lot that I get a bug report while working on the **Development** and I need to fix it on the **Master** branch.

The **Master** branch has an older **node_modules** folder than the **Development** branch.

I've tried working with `Git worktree` creating a **Development** folder and **Master** folder but I can't  checkout to those branches, I get the error: `Cannot checkout because it is already checkout.` and Git doesn't track any changes made in the worktree **Development** for example.

This is what I try:

```
nick-laptop@DESKTOP-6CSCJ00 MINGW64 ~/representin/main (master)
$ git worktree add ../representin-app-dev development
Preparing worktree (checking out 'development')
HEAD is now at 5b352ce8 Wip nav v5

$ git worktree list
C:/Users/nick-laptop/representin/main                 877853b1 [master]
C:/Users/nick-laptop/representin/representin-app-dev  5b352ce8 [development]

$ git checkout development
fatal: 'development' is already checked out at 'C:/Users/nick-laptop/representin/representin-app-dev'
```

Comment: What command did you execute exactly ? can you edit the question with the exact set of commands please.

Comment: @lee-pai-long I have edited the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't checkout the same branch in two worktrees, so to work on your `development` branch you need to `cd` to `../representin-app-dev`.

This way your main repository worktree `~/representin/main` is checked out on master and the linked one `../representin-app-dev` is checked out on `development`.

Open both directory in different terminal session and you'll be able to work on both simultaneously.

---

So base on the comments here is the all process:

- List all worktrees with `git worktree list`
- Delete all worktrees that are not tagged as *main* with `git worktree remove <path-of-the-directory>`
- Make sure your current branch is **master** or `git checkout master`
- Create a new worktree for **development** with `git worktree add ../representin-app-dev development`
- Go to ../representin-app-dev with `cd ../representin-app-dev`
  here your have the development branch checked out, if you do a `git status` you should see it.

Now if you go to the main one `cd ~/representin/main` you're on master, if you go to the other one `cd ../representin-app-dev` you're on development.

Comment: Whenever I try to switch from Master branch to Development branch(not the worktree one) i get this error: [link](https://i.ibb.co/brMmqhL/Knipsel.png)

Comment: That is the same error as your question but with the other branch, i.e master. You can't have the same branch checked out on two worktree.

Comment: Ok, so I have a GitHub repo with the branches **Development** and **Master** and on both i have code, so what do I need to do in order to make the already excisting remote **Development** have a different node_modules folder. The command I did just made a new branch on GitHub.